# Channel non-determinism using context timeouts, deadlocks

Tags: go, deadlock, channel, goroutine

I'm trying to understand contexts and channels in Go, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around what's happening. Here's some example code.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/time/rate"
)

func main() {
    msgs := make(chan string)

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 1*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    limiter := rate.NewLimiter(rate.Every(2*time.Second), 1)

    go func(ctx context.Context, limiter *rate.Limiter) {
        for {
            limiter.Wait(context.Background())

            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                log.Printf("finished!")
                return
            case msg := <-msgs:
                log.Printf("receiving a message: %s", msg)
            }
        }
    }(ctx, limiter)

    defer close(msgs)

    i := 0
    for {
        msgs <- fmt.Sprintf("sending message %d", i)
        i++
        if i > 10 {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

The results I'm getting are non-deterministic. Sometimes the logger prints out three messages, sometimes it's five. Also, the program ends in a deadlock every time:

```
2021/12/31 02:07:21 receiving a message: sending message 0
2021/12/31 02:07:23 receiving a message: sending message 1
2021/12/31 02:07:25 receiving a message: sending message 2
2021/12/31 02:07:27 receiving a message: sending message 3
2021/12/31 02:07:29 receiving a message: sending message 4
2021/12/31 02:07:29 finished!
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

So, I guess I have a couple of questions:

- Why doesn't my goroutine simply end after one second?
- Why is there a deadlock? How can I avoid deadlocks of this nature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why doesn't my goroutine simply end after one second?

While the goroutine may wait here instead of the `select`:

```
limiter.Wait(context.Background())
```

> Why is there a deadlock? How can I avoid deadlocks of this nature?

It is your main goroutine which is getting stuck. It happens here:

```
msgs <- fmt.Sprintf("sending message %d", I)
```

There are no goroutines that would read from `msgs`, so it waits forever.

Here is one of the ways to make it work:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/time/rate"
)

func main() {
    msgs := make(chan string)

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    limiter := rate.NewLimiter(rate.Every(1*time.Second), 1)

    go func() {
        for {
            limiter.Wait(context.Background())

            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                log.Printf("finished!")
                return
            case msg := <-msgs:
                log.Printf("receiving a message: %s", msg)
            }
        }
    }()

    defer close(msgs)

    for i := 0; i < 100000; i++ {
        select {
        case msgs <- fmt.Sprintf("sending message %d", i):
        case <-ctx.Done():
            log.Printf("finished too!")
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to figure it out, but because your answer is so detailed I'm gonna send an upvote your way. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Sending or receiving a message using `<-` is a blocking operation. When the context timeout finishes, the goroutine has now exited and the caller can't proceed.

```
// Goroutine has finished, this call will never finish
msgs <- fmt.Sprintf("sending message %d", i)
```

At this point the program has resulted in a deadlock.

As for the non-determinism, the goroutine and the main execution context run concurrently. Because there are two `for` loops without much delay, the threads are competing with each other. There is no guarantee that they will execute in the same fashion every time.